Characterization of Ulrich bundles in weighted projective space
I am currently getting into Ulrich bundles on surfaces (defined over $\mathbb{C}$). I know that for surfaces in $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ there exists the following characterization of Ulrich bundles on $X$. It says that for sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ supported on $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ the following are equivalent:

$\mathcal{F}$ is Ulrich (i.e. $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is a trivial bundle for all finite linear projections $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^2$).
$h^i(X, \mathcal{F}(-i)) = 0$ for $i = 1,2$ and $h^i(X, \mathcal{F}(-i-1)) = 0$ for $i = 0,1$.

(See for example Theorem 2.1. in this linked article)
As pointed out by Daniel in the comments, the property of 'being Ulrich' in general depends on the embedding of $X$ into projective space.
My setting is, however, that $X$ is a del Pezzo surface of degree 2, which I identify as a double cover
$\pi: X \cong Proj(\mathbb{C}[y,x_0,x_1,x_2]/(y^2 - q(x_0,x_1,x_2)) \to \mathbb{P}^2$
ramified at a smooth quartic curve $Q = V(q)$. Here the variable $y$ has degree 2, so $X$ lives in $\mathbb{P}(2,1,1,1)$. I have a sheaf on $X$, of which I would like to decide if it is Ulrich (in the sense that its pushforward along $\pi$ is trivial), and I would like to use a characterization similar to the one above. My question is: Does such a characterization exist, and if so: Which way do I have to worry regarding the twisting of $\mathcal{F}$, given that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is not naturally defined as my underlying polynomial ring is not generated in degree 1?
My two approaches so far:

Change nothing: $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is still the same as the invertible sheaf associated to a hyperplane section (i.e. the zero set of a linear polynomial $l(x_0,x_1,x_2)$).
First embed $\mathbb{P}(2,1,1,1)$ (and hence $X$) into a suitable unweighted projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ (e.g. by passing to the graded ring $\mathbb{C}[w,x_0,x_1,x_2]_{2\bullet}$, which should give an embedding into $\mathbb{P}^6$). There the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is well-defined and I can use the usual characterization of Ulrich sheaves.

Personally, I assume that the second approach should be the right one, since it should work independently of whether the first approach works or not. If so, how would I go about applying my given characterization. Need I work in $\mathbb{P}^6$ or is it possible to just pull back $\mathcal{O}(i)$ to $X$?
All the best and thanks in advance

Is the property of 'being Ulrich" dependent on the projective embedding? If so, it seems like the question is ambiguous since you're not specifying which projective embedding you're asking $\mathcal{F}$ to be Ulrich with respect to.

Hm, I looked up how this is done in some different papers. Generally, it is assumed that a projective scheme $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ is given, and the question is to decide if a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ is Ulrich.
Besides I found one paper where this is done without an a priori given embedding. There one is given a (smooth) projective variety X and a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ is said to be Ulrich with respect to a very ample divisor $H$ on $X$, if and only if the cohomological conditions
$h^i(X, \mathcal{F}(-pH)) = 0$
are satisfied for $0 \leq i, 1 \leq p \leq \dim(X)$.

As to the question which embedding I want $\mathcal{F}$ to be Ulrich with respect to - I now realize that this is probably the better question to ask: Since 'being Ulrich' is usually defined as a property dependent on a given embedding into projective space, how do I interpret this concept in the case of a scheme $X$ with a given embedding, but into weighted projective space?
